# How to install Ubuntu on Second internal drive on mac?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, mac, macosx

Basically, i have a macbook with a 2nd internal hard drive, I want to dedicate that whole 2nd drive to Ubuntu and install it just on that drive.  Is it possible?

I can't seem to find any tutorials anywhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be entirely possible, [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) seems to be sensible. From what I've read on other tutorials, it's essential to install a utility called rEFInd, as Macs need their EFI boot loader to be modified correctly.

There are also some brief notes from a user who has completed the process earlier this year [here](http://www.datamungeblog.com/2015/02/ubuntu-dual-boot-on-macbook-pro.html).

[This link](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#installsh) has details on installing rEFInd, near the bottom of the page it has instructions for installing on another disk.

Comment: But does this apply to installing Ubuntu on a second internal drive, rather than both OS's sharing one drive and having separate partitions?

Because both links only mention separate partitions, not separate drives.

Comment: I think, so long as the drive is recognised, you should be able to create a partition for Ubuntu which uses the whole of the 2nd drive. It is likely that the first drive will be labelled as /dev/sda and the 2nd as /dev/sdb. Just don't do the partition resizing parts.

Comment: I've just edited the answer to add a link which includes details of installing  rEFInd on a separate drive.

Comment: I reckon installing it rEFInd on the second disk will do it! I'm being paranoid, because I found some [old article](https://blog.christophersmart.com/2009/11/27/linux-on-mac-pro-with-multiple-drives/) saying they tried installing Fedora with rEFIt on a second drive and it didn't work, but found [this solution.](http://blog.christophersmart.com/2009/12/22/linux-on-mac-pro-with-multiple-drives-for-real-this-time/) It just got me worried that i may run into the same problems with ubuntu and rEFInd, plus I'm pretty new to this dual booting business (n00b).

Comment: I've just edited the last link as it was for rEFIt not rEFInd! Your best bet is to make a backup, then give it a go. Format the other drive with OSX's Disk Utility, and ensure that you know which drive and partition has your OSX installation on it, so you definitely don't overwrite it.

Comment: so it seems i can't find ubuntu on the boot menu after installing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @lthomas112: The next step can be found at [The rEFInd Boot Manager:
Methods of Booting Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/linux.html). Are you trying to boot GRUB 2 or boot directly to Ubuntu using the EFI stub loader?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to reply, i worked around it, i accidentally unmounted rEFInd, so i remounted it, then held 'c' on boot (because my macbook has a 2nd HDD instead of CDD) and it booted in Ubuntu. Thanks for all your help!!!